# android send email with files

Tags: android, file, email

I need to send email(using only email clients) with multiple files. How can I do this?
When I trying to use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE i cant to get only email clients, but when I use ACTION_SENDTO i cant to attach files.My code

```
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected documents count = " + documents.size());
        if (documents.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Intent sendMailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        sendMailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for (Document document : documents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FilePath = " + document.getLocalPdfFile());
            uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + document.getLocalPdfFile()));
        }

        sendMailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivity(sendMailIntent);
```

This code work fine. It send files. The problem is how to show to user only email clients,couse ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE action can be handled by many other programms.

Comment: "I need to send email(using only email clients) with multiple files" -- no, you need to let the user do what the user wants. If the user wants to send email, fine. If the user wants to use some other option to handle those files, fine. It is the user's device, the user's files, the user's apps, the user's battery life, the user's bandwidth, etc. Please allow the user to use their device the way that the user wants.

Comment: `EXTRA_STREAM` expects a String or a Uri, not an arraylist of Uris, or anything else.

Comment: Rename your button to "Send", or use `ShareActionProvider`. Then, use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. You instantly make your app more useful and avoid "this problem".

Comment: Sorry, I just using ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE (copied wrong code). My problem is how to show to user only email clients,couse this action can be handled not only by email clients. It mean that user will see many other programs in chooser list.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I found was sometimes gmail picks up the attachments fine, but not native email clients, sometimes the other way round.

Try ACTION_SEND, you may have a few extra options in your chooser, but I found it much more reliable.

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    //....same as in your code.

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Good luck.

Comment: This code will also ask user to choose a program from the list, which will contain all applications that can handle ACTION_SEND, not only email clients.

Comment: like i said "you may have a few extra options in your chooser"